# How to display textbox value dynamically which is get from database using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I got value from database and then i need to set those value to textbox. I have created a controller file with the method name of **edit** look like below

**userdata.blade.php:**

```
 public function edit($id)
{
        echo "You have clicked edit link".$name;
        $editdata = DB::table('newuser')->where('Id','=',$id)->get();
        return View::make('editdata',array('list' => $editdata));
}
```

I have passed array of value as parameter to the view file.now i need to diaplay the value of name to textbox.how to do that in html page using laravel. My html page look like below

**editdata.blade.php:**

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <div>
       {{Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method' => 'post'))}}
         {{Form::label('name','Name',array('id'=>'label-name'))}}
         {{Form::text('name',{{$list->Name}}}}
       {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

can anyone tell me that what mistake i did.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the curly brackets, you are already "inside" PHP code and don't need them:

```
{{ Form::text('name',$list->Name) }}
```

Also you get a collection from your controller you probably want to do:

```
$editdata = DB::table('newuser')->where('Id','=',$id)->first();
```

Or even:

```
$editdata = DB::table('newuser')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a collection (multiple rows) and not the model itself. You can use `User::find($id)` which gives you direct access to the model with the specified Id.

When not using eloquent just replace `get()` with `first()`